# WPF Membership Provider Custom User Profile

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-membership

I have a web application and a WPF application sharing a Support project for utilities.

When trying to get my custom membership user profile working on the WPF project I am getting an error and am unsure what to look for.

The error occurs when calling the GetUser method in the support project from the WPF project, the error is -

Could not load type 'APP.Support.UserProfile' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

The User profile code is -

```
namespace APP.Support
{
public class UserProfile : ProfileBase
{
    static public UserProfile CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            return (UserProfile)
                    (ProfileBase.Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName));
        }
    }

    public static UserProfile GetUser(string username)
    {
        return (UserProfile)
                    (ProfileBase.Create(username));
    }

    public string UserCode
    {
        get { return ((string)(base["UserCode"])); }
        set { base["UserCode"] = value; Save(); }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return ((string)(base["Name"])); }
        set { base["Name"] = value; Save(); }
    }

    public string UserID
    {
        get { return ((string)(base["UserID"])); }
        set { base["UserID"] = value; Save(); }
    }
}
```

}

The web config (which works) is -

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="30">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" connectionStringName="MembershipConnectionString" applicationName="APP" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="2147483647" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add connectionStringName="MembershipConnectionString" applicationName="APP" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<profile defaultProvider="SqlProvider" inherits="APP.Support.UserProfile">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="MembershipConnectionString" applicationName="APP"/>
  </providers>
</profile>
```

The app config from the WPF project that cannot call this is -

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="30">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" connectionStringName="MembershipConnectionString" applicationName="APP" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="2147483647" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add connectionStringName="MembershipConnectionString" applicationName="APP" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<profile defaultProvider="SqlProvider" inherits="APP.Support.UserProfile">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="MembershipConnectionString" applicationName="APP"/>
  </providers>
</profile>
```

The calling code is -

```
Application.Current.Properties["UserName"] = username;

UserProfile profile = UserProfile.GetUser(username);

Application.Current.Properties["LoggedInUser"] = profile.Name;
```

Comment: Note - I am assuming that it is because a WPF windows application cannot use the aspnet membership provider, however membership.GetAllUsers() works fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should anyone else be in this situation, it does not appear to be possible.

I ended up writing some SQL methods in my support project to retrieve the user profile information.

The profile information in the Membership database is stored in a rather strange way but it is extractable -

PropertyNames - UserCode:S:0:2:Name:S:2:9:UserID:S:11:8:

PropertyValues - XXTEST USER00000001